# Local installation specific configuration for a Ruby gem application

Tags: ruby, spring-boot, rubygems, bundler

Disclaimer: I know ruby since quite long as language and i am a experienced programmer from the Java corner,  but haven't really dealt deeply with the whole eco - culture of Ruby. I always liked Ruby, but only now I am starting to use Rubygems with Bundler and i am impressed. So i am assuming there is an easy answer to my question , which proves my ignorance ;-)

One thing i really like about gems and bundler is that you can package and distribute libraries and applications or even both... neat.

Let's keep it simple. Let's say i have a script, which does something in a database and which want to package and distribute with bundler with enterprise specific gems server. For the configuration of this script i need a db url, a userid and a password. The password should likely be encrypted.  This configuration should be externalized in a host resp. installation specific config file.

In the Java Spring Boot world, where i am coming from , they have this mechanism with application.properties which can be a mix of build time,  installation and runtime parameters and can be accessed through a common api.

I saw in the bundler documentation that one pass the local configuration file upon installation time : https://bundler.io/v1.5/bundle_config.html. Neat. But i am not quite sure how this could/ should work in detail. Here real world examples would help...

Is there a canonical form to have and deal with installation specific configurations for ruby apps distributed with gems and bundler?

Any pointers , input , feedback is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal setting storage system in Ruby applications.

[dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) is popular for plain Ruby applications. Rails has [its own system](https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336).

Comment: dotenv looks promising...  do you know if it can look at other places then the working directory for .env files ?

Comment: probably yes , since Dotenv.load take also files as parameter and also dotenv -f

Comment: This looks also quite promising https://github.com/railsware/global